# Django get a clean return from subprocess.Popen at celery

Tags: python, django, shell, subprocess

i have a celery task that calls a subprocess.Popen aka shell cmd but for some reasone not the output of the cmd gets saved to the user field but the process memory id !?!?

```
[2019-02-09 21:35:05,526: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: MyProject.tasks.allocate_new_btc_address[08d7db34-5710-4224-be07-c968599d9039]  
[2019-02-09 21:35:05,540: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f31063d79b0>
[2019-02-09 21:35:05,540: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-9] MyProject.tasks.allocate_new_btc_address[08d7db34-5710-4224-be07-c968599d9039]: New BTC address has been allocated to a user account
[2019-02-09 21:35:05,540: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-9] Task MyProject.tasks.allocate_new_btc_address[08d7db34-5710-4224-be07-c968599d9039] succeeded in 0.012948354000400286s: None
iubcasiuiuBIUcb723iub7c8732iewe
```

tasks.py

```
@app.task
def allocate_new_btc_address(user_pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
    new_address = subprocess.Popen(['electrum', 'createnewaddress'])
    try:
        user.acc_btc_addr = new_address
        user.save()
        print(new_address)
        logger.info("New BTC address has been allocated to a user account")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

thats the vaule that gets saved to the field:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f31063d79b0>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popen returns an object. To get the output directly, use subprocess.check_output() function:

```
from subprocess import check_output
new_address = check_output(['electrum', 'createnewaddress'])
```

Comment: Got it working like this: new_address = subprocess.Popen("electrum createnewaddress", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()